# Merge multiple matrices row-wise and store it in a new matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to read a  large file (*hap_file*) part by part as matrices using scan() function in R i.e

```
x=  matrix(scan(hap_file, what = "character",quiet = TRUE, nlines=2500000))
y=  matrix(scan(hap_file, what = "character",quiet = TRUE, skip=2500000, nlines=2500000))
z=  matrix(scan(hap_file, what = "character",quiet = TRUE, skip=5000000, nlines=2500000))
```

The *hap_file* has 1006 rows and 7500000 columns and contains only 0, 1, 2 (tab delimited). When I try to read the hap_file using scan() as a whole, it gives me "*too many items*"  **error** .
So I have chosen to read it in parts using scan(). Am I doing it right?

And to combine the matrices row-wise, for which I use rbind function:

```
tmp_haplos =  matrix(rbind(x, y, z),nrow = tmp.nhap)
```

But I get an error saying  :

> Error in rbind(x, y, z) : negative extents to matrix

What does this error mean and  how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What's `tmp.nhap`? What do x, y and z look like (we don't have your files)?

Comment: @jogo Please see the updated question

Comment: @Spacedman its the total no. of rows in hap_file . Please see the updated question.

Comment: 2^31 < 1006*75e5 https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2004-February/028870.html You shifted the  "too many items"-problem from `scan()` to `rbind()` Eventually you can use `big.matrix()` from the package `bigmemory`

Comment: Thanks @jogo will try 'bigmemory' package

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bigmemory` or `ff` packages. Please see below example of read\write of large datasets with `ff` package:

```
library(ff)

# Simulation
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
m <- 100
fd <- as.ffdf(as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:2, n * m, replace = TRUE), ncol = m, nrow = n)))

write.csv.ffdf(fd, file =  "test.csv")


# Read to ffdf 
fd_read <- read.csv.ffdf(file = "test.csv", header = TRUE)
matprint(fd_read)
```

Output:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8   V93 V94 V95 V96 V97 V98 V99 V100
1     0  0  0  0  0  0  1  2 :   1   0   2   1   2   0   0    2
2     2  1  0  2  2  2  1  1 :   2   0   1   0   2   1   1    1
3     1  0  0  1  1  2  1  0 :   0   1   1   0   1   2   1    2
4     2  2  1  1  2  1  1  2 :   1   2   0   0   0   0   1    1
5     2  2  1  0  0  0  0  0 :   0   0   1   1   1   2   2    2
6     0  1  1  1  0  0  2  2 :   2   1   0   2   2   0   2    1
7     1  2  1  2  2  0  0  1 :   0   2   2   2   0   2   0    2
8     2  0  0  1  0  1  2  0 :   1   2   0   0   0   0   2    2
:     :  :  :  :  :  :  :  : :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :    :
993   1  2  2  1  2  0  1  2 :   0   2   0   2   0   1   2    1
994   1  0  0  2  2  1  2  1 :   1   0   0   2   0   1   2    2
995   1  0  2  1  1  1  0  2 :   0   2   2   0   1   1   2    1
996   2  2  0  0  0  2  1  0 :   2   2   0   1   1   2   2    2
997   1  0  2  2  2  2  0  0 :   2   1   0   2   2   0   1    1
998   1  2  0  2  0  2  0  2 :   1   1   1   2   1   2   0    0
999   2  1  1  0  2  2  2  2 :   1   1   2   1   0   0   1    2
1000  0  1  2  1  0  2  2  1 :   1   2   0   1   2   0   2    0
```